# Split tmux.conf into multiple files?

Tags: tmux

I have a file of common tmux settings I share between computers (tmux.conf.common). I'd like to be able to source this file in my tmux.conf. A way to accomplish this in bash is to have the each computer's .bashrc source the common file. Is there a way to do something analogous in tmux?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `.tmux.conf` format has the `source-file` directive which can be used the same way. Using `source` also works.

```
source-file /path/to/tmux.conf.common
```

Comment: Is there a way to use source-file with an environment path?

source-file $tmuxpath/navigation.tmux

Comment: I don't see why not.  Tmux conf in general let's you expand environment variables.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm getting the error message "/navigation.tmux" not found. I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: Nvm... I was sshd into my box with putty using the console, I made a new path variable name TMUX_DIR and it wasn't being updated for some reason.... I'm not sure why this is the case. However, when I ran a termite terminal (spawned from the console) it worked fine. Not sure why the terminal environment wasn't updating...

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but this is how I use it across my workstations and deployed servers in order to be able to share my general preferences and easily override them.

First I just moved my .tmux.conf to a tmux.common then sourced it in the now empty tmux.conf
then I distributed this basic tmux.conf tmux.common to all nodes.

Since the last line in the tmux.common is run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
Any additional plugins need to be mentioned before the sourced file.

If needed this could easily be expanded to include more common files, for instance for making devel/test / acceptance/production systems have different colors or whatnot.

#### generic .tmux.conf

```
#
# Include commons settings, shared between systems, anything but plugin
# related stuff can come after, like overriding common bindings or settings.
# Plugin stuff needs to be specified before this!
#
source-file ~/nocloud/conf/tmux.common
```

#### workstation .tmux.conf

On my workstations I use a layout plugin, this helps to make me aware if the tmux session is local or remote, and if remote, I have to look closer at the hostname, to ensure I am doing whatever it is to the right one.

```
set -g @plugin "arcticicestudio/nord-tmux"

#
# Include commons settings, shared between systems, anything but plugin
# related stuff can come after, like overriding common bindings or settings.
# Plugin stuff needs to be specified before this!
#
source-file ~/Dropbox/SharedConfigs/multi-os-apps/tmux.common
```