# How to get current path of source-file in the sourced file itself

Tags: tmux

In a VIM script file, you have access to `<sfile>` as [demonstrated in this question and answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976776/how-to-get-path-to-the-current-vimscript-being-executed). A few examples from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734557/627727):

> ```
> " Absolute path of script file:
> let s:path = expand('<sfile>:p')
>
> " Absolute path of script file with symbolic links resolved:
> let s:path = resolve(expand('<sfile>:p'))
>
> " Folder in which script resides: (not safe for symlinks)
> let s:path = expand('<sfile>:p:h')
> ```

TMUX supports the ability to source additional using `source-file` ([see this StackOverflow question and answer regarding for splitting TMUX configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106611/split-tmux-conf-into-multiple-files)).

Now, to my queston. Let's say in my example in my `~/.tmux.conf` I have a line like below

```
source-file ~/some-workspace-dir/my-tmux.conf
```

I'd like to be able to refer to files relative to `my-tmux.conf` inside of `my-tmux.conf`.

If I add a `run-shell "pwd"`, it just points out the home directory at `~/.tmux.conf` rather than `~/some-workspace-dir`, the directory containing `my-tmux.conf`.

My question is *how do you get the current path of a file being sourced by TMUX `source-file`* (without parsing the sourced file)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest translating the file you're calling from a tmux config to a shell script, and calling it via `run-shell` instead of `source-file` - that way you can use e.g. `dirname`/`basename` to derive the path of the sourced file.

Converting a tmux config to a shell script is usually as easy as prefixing each command with the path to tmux, i.e. starting with hello_world.tmux:

```
command-prompt -p "enter a name: " "display-message 'hello %1!'"
```

...this becomes hello_world.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/tmux command-prompt -p "enter a name: " "display-message 'hello %1!'"
```

Here is a script that demonstrates some introspection in action:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
BASENAME=$(basename "$0")
tmux split-window -v
sleep 1
tmux send-keys -t :.1 "cat $CURRENT_DIR/$BASENAME"
```

If you run this shell script from inside tmux, it will determine its own path on the filesystem, then create a new pane inside tmux, and sends a cat command to the shell running inside that pane, printing the shell script's own source code.

Here is an Asciinema screencast, demoing the script in action: https://asciinema.org/a/418522

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer seems to have changed since this was first answered. tmux 3.2 added an option which trivializes the issue [^1](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES#L199) [^2](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/71fc9f3ee8753a2bb163c85c784936a8d6d3e0ac). In the file config file which you want to locate (i.e.: ~/.tmux.conf or ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf):

```
run-shell "#{d:current_file}/path/to/plugin.tmux"
#            | ^ crux of the issue
#            ^ dirname
```

The man page for tmux indicates the command given to `run-shell` is formatted using tmux's templating syntax [^3](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html). The FORMATS section indicates there is a variable named `current_file` which may be used to locate the currently executing configuration file. Additionally, the prefix `d:` can be used to get the dirname of that file. Hence, `#{d:current_file}` will get the configuration directory.